# Whether below figure on atmospheric pressure is correct?

Tags: atmospheric-science

How conservation of energy is explained in the below figure? It seems atmospheric pressure in multiplication of Area(P*A) is balanced by m*g. If this is correct then if we take bigger diameter pot, the resultant force will increase and ultimately rise of mercury. Is it all correct?

[image]

Comment: The pressure does not depend on the area, the height of the mercury column is determined by the pressure: $\rho gh=P_{atm}$.

Comment: Fluid equilibrium equation is $\nabla P=\rho \vec {g}$.